# How to use pgAdmin4 to view the (dump)data downloaded from Heroku

Tags: heroku, pgadmin-4

I backed up the database on Heroku,
and downloaded the file (dump file) locally.

```
heroku pg:backups capture --app $app_name$
heroku pg:backups:download -a $app_name$
```

Then, I would like to check the contents of the dump file using pgAdmin4.
After setting up pgAdmin, I get the "success" message,
but I don't know where I can see the data. Please let me know.

**"Success message" here:**

[image: "success message" here]

For reference, the procedure for setting up pgAdmin is as follows.

Database > schemas > public > tables, right-click on the table I have created.
The settings are as follows.

[image: setting here]

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the data into the table, you just right click on the same table and select `view/edit data` option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
When I use 'view/edit data' option to read the file, I get the following error.

'File type not supported'

How can I see the contents of the (dump)file downloaded from Heroku's Database?

Comment: If it is a binary file then you can't see the contents unless you load the data somewhere.

Comment: I tried to connect to a database on Heroku from pgAdmin locally.
The database files appear in the local pgAdmin dashboard,
However,I can't open the files and get this message.

"FATAL: permission denied for database "d1a1vjvtcdfr6p"
DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege."

If you could give me some advice, I would appreciate it.

Thank you,